MPI_Win_lock seems to be working in one host but not on several hosts
I wrote a program to create a job-stealing work queue in a distributed system, using MPI.  There is a number of jobs to be completed and there is an index to advance through the list of all possible jobs. The jobs do not take the same amount of time to be completed. Each MPI process can work on a range of jobs. An MPI_Window is used to store an index which marks the beginning of the abovementioned range. The index is initialized by the root process as being zero. Each process accesses the index using MPI_Win_lock(), and uses MPI_Get() to obtain the index and MPI_Put() to store the value of index which marks the end of the range of jobs the process will work on, before releasing the window with MPI_Win_unlock(). The process which gained access to the index then proceeds to perform the work, this is repeated until all the work is completed.
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int do_work(int r, int bgn_pos, int end_pos){
    int time = rand() % 10 + 1;
    
    std::cout << "Rank " << r << " working " << time << " second(s), [" << bgn_pos << ", " << end_pos << ")." << std::endl;
    
    sleep(time);

    std::cout << "    Rank " << r << " finished." << std::endl;

    return time;
}

int main(){

    MPI_Init(0, 0);
    
    int root = 0;
    MPI_Comm communicator = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(communicator, &rank);
    srand(rank);
    
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(communicator, &world_size);

    // Total number of jobs.
    //
    int n = 250;

    // Number of jobs to be batch-processed.
    //
    int chunk_size = 20;
    
    // Time each process takes.
    //
    int time = 0;
    
    // Number of chunks each process deals with.
    //
    int number_of_chunks = 0;
    
    // What each rank is going to process, the semiopen interval [bgn_pos, end_pos).
    //
    int bgn_pos, end_pos;

    // Window (only in root).
    //
    MPI_Win win;
    
    // Allocate the window.
    //
    int *pos_in_queue; // Position of the work in the queue.
    int rv = MPI_Win_allocate(1*sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, communicator, &pos_in_queue, &win);

    // Initialize the position in the queue as zero.
    //
    if (rank == root){
        *pos_in_queue = 0;
    }
    
    MPI_Barrier(communicator);
    
    // Process jobs.
    //
    while (true){
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, root, 0, win);

            MPI_Get(&bgn_pos, 1 /* origin_count */, MPI_INT, root, 0 /* target_disp */,
                1 /* target_count */, MPI_INT, win);
                
            if (bgn_pos >= n){
                // Nothing to do, unlock and get out (no need to alter pos_in_queue).
                //
                MPI_Win_unlock(root, win);
                
                break;
            }
                
            end_pos = std::min(bgn_pos + chunk_size, n);
                
            MPI_Put(&end_pos, 1 /* int origin_count */, MPI_INT, root, 0 /* MPI_Aint target_disp */,
                1 /* int target_count */, MPI_INT, win);
                
        MPI_Win_unlock(root, win);
        
        // Do work.
        //
        time += do_work(rank, bgn_pos, end_pos);
        number_of_chunks++;
    
        if (end_pos >= n) break;
    }
    
    MPI_Barrier(communicator);

    MPI_Win_free(&win);    
    
    printf("Rank %d, time = %d, chunks = %d.\n", rank, time, number_of_chunks);
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}

In this case there are 250 jobs to be done and each process works on intervals of size 20.
If I run this program in a single node using the following command (assume the name of the executable is jobsteal):
mpirun -np 4 ./jobsteal
the output is as follows:
    Rank 0 working 4 second(s), [60, 80).
    Rank 1 working 4 second(s), [40, 60).
    Rank 2 working 1 second(s), [0, 20).
    Rank 3 working 7 second(s), [20, 40).
        Rank 2 finished.
    Rank 2 working 10 second(s), [80, 100).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 0 working 7 second(s), [120, 140).
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1 working 7 second(s), [100, 120).
        Rank 3 finished.
    Rank 3 working 6 second(s), [140, 160).
        Rank 0 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
    Rank 1 working 8 second(s), [160, 180).
    Rank 0 working 8 second(s), [200, 220).
    Rank 2 working 9 second(s), [180, 200).
        Rank 3 finished.
    Rank 3 working 9 second(s), [220, 240).
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1 working 6 second(s), [240, 250).
        Rank 0 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1, time = 25, chunks = 4.
    Rank 0, time = 19, chunks = 3.
    Rank 2, time = 20, chunks = 3.
    Rank 3, time = 22, chunks = 3.

This seems to be working well. However, if I create a hostfile (specifying a single slot per node) and run the same executable in a cluster with 8 nodes, the results are baffling:
    Rank 0 working 4 second(s), [0, 20).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 0 working 7 second(s), [20, 40).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 0 working 8 second(s), [40, 60).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 4 working 2 second(s), [60, 22).
    Rank 0 working 6 second(s), [22, 42).
    Rank 1 working 4 second(s), [22, 22).
    Rank 2 working 1 second(s), [22, 22).
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 3 working 7 second(s), [42, 22).
    Rank 5 working 6 second(s), [22, 22).
    Rank 0 working 4 second(s), [22, 42).
    Rank 6 working 2 second(s), [22, 22).
    Rank 7 working 8 second(s), [22, 22).
        Rank 6 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 1 working 7 second(s), [42, 42).
    Rank 2 working 10 second(s), [42, 42).
    Rank 0 working 6 second(s), [80, 100).
    Rank 4 working 4 second(s), [42, 80).
        Rank 5 finished.
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 7 finished.
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 0 working 7 second(s), [42, 62).
    Rank 6 working 6 second(s), [100, 42).
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 6 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 4 working 5 second(s), [62, 62).
    Rank 3 working 6 second(s), [62, 62).
    Rank 5 working 6 second(s), [62, 42).
    Rank 0 working 3 second(s), [42, 62).
    Rank 7 working 10 second(s), [42, 42).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 6 working 3 second(s), [62, 120).
    Rank 1 working 8 second(s), [120, 62).
    Rank 0 working 10 second(s), [62, 82).
    Rank 2 working 9 second(s), [62, 62).
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 5 finished.
        Rank 6 finished.
        Rank 7 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 0 working 2 second(s), [82, 102).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 0 working 3 second(s), [102, 122).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 1 working 6 second(s), [122, 140).
    Rank 2 working 6 second(s), [140, 82).
    Rank 4 working 7 second(s), [82, 82).
    Rank 0 working 8 second(s), [82, 102).
    Rank 3 working 9 second(s), [82, 82).
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 5 working 1 second(s), [102, 82).
    Rank 6 working 6 second(s), [82, 82).
    Rank 0 working 1 second(s), [62, 82).
    Rank 7 working 10 second(s), [82, 62).
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 5 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 1 working 4 second(s), [82, 142).
    Rank 2 working 2 second(s), [142, 160).
    Rank 0 working 10 second(s), [102, 122).
    Rank 4 working 4 second(s), [160, 102).
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 6 finished.
        Rank 7 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 3 working 1 second(s), [122, 102).
    Rank 0 working 4 second(s), [122, 142).
    Rank 5 working 3 second(s), [102, 122).
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 5 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 6 working 9 second(s), [142, 102).
    Rank 7 working 2 second(s), [102, 102).
    Rank 1 working 6 second(s), [102, 102).
    Rank 2 working 9 second(s), [102, 162).
    Rank 0 working 7 second(s), [180, 200).
    Rank 4 working 8 second(s), [162, 180).
        Rank 7 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 3 working 6 second(s), [200, 142).
    Rank 0 working 1 second(s), [122, 142).
    Rank 5 working 7 second(s), [142, 122).
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 1 working 7 second(s), [142, 122).
    Rank 0 working 7 second(s), [122, 142).
    Rank 7 working 6 second(s), [122, 122).
        Rank 6 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 5 finished.
        Rank 7 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 0 working 3 second(s), [182, 202).
    Rank 4 working 6 second(s), [142, 182).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 6 working 6 second(s), [202, 162).
    Rank 7 working 4 second(s), [162, 142).
    Rank 1 working 3 second(s), [142, 162).
    Rank 2 working 5 second(s), [162, 122).
    Rank 5 working 3 second(s), [122, 162).
    Rank 0 working 7 second(s), [220, 240).
    Rank 3 working 1 second(s), [162, 220).
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
        Rank 5 finished.
        Rank 7 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 6 finished.
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 0 working 2 second(s), [240, 250).
        Rank 0 finished.
    Rank 7 working 7 second(s), [250, 182).
    Rank 1 working 10 second(s), [182, 162).
    Rank 2 working 8 second(s), [162, 182).
    Rank 4 working 4 second(s), [182, 162).
    Rank 5 working 1 second(s), [162, 142).
    Rank 6 working 7 second(s), [142, 222).
    Rank 3 working 3 second(s), [222, 182).
        Rank 5 finished.
    Rank 5 working 10 second(s), [182, 182).
        Rank 3 finished.
    Rank 3 working 7 second(s), [182, 242).
        Rank 4 finished.
    Rank 4 working 9 second(s), [242, 202).
        Rank 7 finished.
        Rank 6 finished.
    Rank 6 working 4 second(s), [202, 162).
        Rank 2 finished.
    Rank 2 working 6 second(s), [162, 182).
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1 working 2 second(s), [182, 202).
        Rank 3 finished.
    Rank 3 working 2 second(s), [202, 202).
        Rank 5 finished.
    Rank 5 working 4 second(s), [202, 202).
        Rank 6 finished.
    Rank 6 working 3 second(s), [202, 222).
        Rank 3 finished.
    Rank 3 working 5 second(s), [222, 222).
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1 working 3 second(s), [222, 202).
        Rank 4 finished.
    Rank 4 working 6 second(s), [202, 250).
        Rank 2 finished.
    Rank 2 working 8 second(s), [250, 182).
        Rank 6 finished.
    Rank 6 working 9 second(s), [182, 222).
        Rank 5 finished.
    Rank 5 working 2 second(s), [222, 222).
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1 working 8 second(s), [222, 242).
        Rank 5 finished.
    Rank 5 working 7 second(s), [242, 242).
        Rank 3 finished.
    Rank 3 working 9 second(s), [242, 242).
        Rank 4 finished.
        Rank 2 finished.
        Rank 6 finished.
    Rank 6 working 6 second(s), [242, 202).
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1 working 1 second(s), [202, 242).
        Rank 5 finished.
    Rank 5 working 9 second(s), [242, 250).
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 1 working 10 second(s), [250, 222).
        Rank 3 finished.
    Rank 3 working 5 second(s), [222, 250).
        Rank 6 finished.
    Rank 6 working 4 second(s), [250, 250).
        Rank 3 finished.
        Rank 5 finished.
        Rank 6 finished.
        Rank 1 finished.
    Rank 6, time = 65, chunks = 12.
    Rank 5, time = 59, chunks = 12.
    Rank 3, time = 61, chunks = 12.
    Rank 1, time = 79, chunks = 14.
    Rank 4, time = 55, chunks = 10.
    Rank 7, time = 47, chunks = 7.
    Rank 0, time = 110, chunks = 21.
    Rank 2, time = 64, chunks = 10.

It seems like this approach works when all the processes reside in a single physical host. Is there a way to extend the intended behavior to a cluster?
The compiler installed in the cluster is g++, version 9.4.0, the version of OpenMPI is 4.0.3
Thanks in advance to all.

you should not try to access bgn_pos after MPI_Get() untill you call MPI_Win_flush()

Thanks a lot, your solution is correct.

The semantics of MPI_Win_(un)lock are not what most users expect, unfortunately.  MPI_Win_lock may not do anything except mark an epoch has begun.  MPI_Get may do nothing except enqueue this operation for subsequent completion.  Only after MPI_Win_unlock can one be sure that anything has happened.
Gilles already pointed out the practical problem resulting from this semantic.  You should look at the MPI-3 changes to RMA, which provide more control over synchronization.  In your case, you will likely want to MPI_Win_lock_all the window after its allocation (you should MPI_Win_allocate it, which is better than MPI_Win_create.  Then you can use MPI_Win_flush to impart completion.
If you want a proper lock on the window, implement one using MPI_Compare_and_swap (for a simple spin-lock) or do something fancy with queuing locks using Send-Recv (I believe https://www.mpich.org/2012/10/24/implementing-mpi-io-atomic-mode-and-shared-file-pointers-using-mpi-one-sided-communication/ describes an implementation of this).

Hello, thanks for your comment. I will look into the paper you linked. With regards to the MPI_Win_lock_all, unfortunately it allows more than one process to have access to the same jobs, which is very weird.

It's not weird in the context of PGAS programming models like Fortran coarrays, UPC, or Global Arrays.  In any case, the proper way to achieve mutual exclusive for more than one element at a time is to build a lock.

Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.
